# Unlocked Balance 0 , Balance is correct.

Tags: unlocked-balance

recently updated to the new Monero v0.13.0.3 and i am resyncing the entire blockchain, My balance is correct, but my unlocked balance shows 0. Also the 2 old transactions from a few months ago show 0/10 confirmations? The blockchain has still not completed yet. But is this normal? Any help would be appriciated. Can I still spend my "Balance"? Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it's normal. You must only wait to have a full synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

If, as you state, you are resyncing the entire blockchain, you will need to wait untill it has fully downloaded and been scanned by the wallet before being able to spend any unspent balance.